# Установка nginx+mono под CentOS (проблема mono)

Tags: nginx, centos, mono

Первый раз работаю с CentOS. Что было сделано.

- Добавлен репозиторий EPEL в yum.
- Установлен nginx (yum install nginx).
- Установлен mono (yum groupinstall mono) Добавлен скрипт для запуска mono как FastCGI (с сайта mono).
- Зарегистрированы сервисы (если я правильно понял, назначение команды chkconfig --levels 235 nginx on).
- Запущены (service nginx start).

Дальше появились проблемы: не могу получить ответ от nginx. Когда захожу с сервака через lyxn, вижу страницу, с другого компьютера ничего не выходит.

- error.log - пустой.
- access.log - пишет только lynx.
- Подключение через telnet висит долго, результат: сбой подключения.

Решение первой найдено: исправление правил iptables.

Вторая проблема: скрипт для fastcgi не работает.
Листинг:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          monoserve.sh
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start fastcgi mono server with hosts
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/mono
NAME=monoserver
DESC=monoserver

MONOSERVER=$(which fastcgi-mono-server2)
MONOSERVER_PID=$(ps auxf | grep fastcgi-mono-server2.exe | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

WEBAPPS="www.domain1.xyz:/:/var/www/domain1.xyz/,www.domain2.xyz:/:/var/www/domain2.xyz/"

case "$1" in
        start)
                if [ -z "${MONOSERVER_PID}" ]; then
                        echo "starting mono server"
                        ${MONOSERVER} /applications=${WEBAPPS}
/socket=unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket &
                        echo "mono server started"
                else
                        echo ${WEBAPPS}
                        echo "mono server is running"
                fi
        ;;
        stop)
                if [ -n "${MONOSERVER_PID}" ]; then
                        kill ${MONOSERVER_PID}
                        echo "mono server stopped"
                else
                        echo "mono server is not running"
                fi
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Проблема: не может найти fastcgi-mono-server2, что делать пока не знаю.
Есть подозрение что этого компонента нет в пакетах, возможно нет в репозитариях.

Теперь появилась еще одна проблема: сервер не хочет отображать страницу возвращает страницу 500.

Справился путем возвращения соединения через IP 127.0.0.1, но хотелось бы unix сокетами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующие настройки помогли

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/RST limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp parameter-problem
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN recent: SET name: radiator side: source
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN recent: UPDATE seconds: 30 hit_count: 3 name: radiator side: source

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Здесь открыты:

- порт 22 - ssh
- порт 21 – ftp
- порт 80 – http
- порт 443 – https
- порт 25 – smtp
- порт 53 – dns
- Стоит защита от ботов сбрасывающая попытки перебора после 3х на 30
     секунд

Доставил пакеты:

```
   yum install xsp.i386
   yum install mono-addon-xsp.noarch
```

Теперь fastcgi-mono-server2 есть, только в другом месте /opt/novell/mono/bin/fastcgi-mono-server2.

Вернул соединение через 127.0.0.1:9000 и все заработало.

Нашел следующее решение:

```
chmod a+w /tmp/fastcgi.sock
```

открыть доступ на запись в сокет.

Answer (score 0):

Так может, mono, а не nano??

Если локально есть ответ, а удалённо - нет, то у вас не настроен iptables.

Comment: По поводу mono: я не могу проверить пашет или нет, пока не настрою отдачу (странно, мне казалось я mono написал). А iptables стандартно включен? Как его настроить? Я во FreeBSD таких проблем не имел ни разу.

Comment: Во FreeBSD кажется всё открыто по умолчанию, если не ошибаюсь..

Comment: Так и есть, поэтому никаких проблем не было)

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже когда боролся с такой проблемой. nginx и fastcgi-mono связал... Но никак не смог получить нормальной работы с сервисами (.asmx). В итоге был запущен xsp-сервер, кстате и работает он быстрее чем fastcgi-mono.